# Distinct Clause in an SQL Query

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named MediaGenT in my SQL Database that has 425000 records.  However the column name mg_medianum has duplicate entries.  For example mg_medianum = '858' has 10 different records but I am only interested in the most recent record which can be ordered by mg_createdate.

When I do this I get 425000 records:

```
  Select * from MediaGenT
  Order By mg_createdate;
```

When I do this I get 89000 records (correct but only shows one column):

```
  Select distinct mg_medianum from MediaGenT
  Order by mg_createdate;
```

To sum up what I need is one query that shows every column of the 89000 records only displaying the most recent distinct mg_medianum based ordered by mg_createdate.  I'm having trouble coming up with the syntax for that kind of query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

You need a slightly more complicated query:

```
select mgt.*
from MediaGenT mgt join
     (select mg_medianum, max(mg_createdate) as maxcd
      from MediaGenT
      group by mg_medianum
     ) msum
     on mgt.mg_medianum = msum.mg_medianum and mgt.mg_createdate = msum.maxcd;
```

That is, calculate the most recent date for each media num, and then choose that record.

This is standard SQL that should work in any database.

EDIT:

The above query is calculating the maximum date for each media number and calling it `msum.maxcd`.  The query uses this query to select only the maximum date for each media number (via the `join`).  The `mgt.*` expression is choosing all the columns from the `MediaGenT` table.

Comment: thanks gordon this is working fine.  can u just explain the significance behind mgt.* and it's purpose? also what role does maxcd have in this?

Answer (score 1):

This *might* be faster than Gordon's solution due to the fact that only a single scan on the table is needed.

```
select mg_medianum, mg_createdate
from (
    select mg_medianum, 
           mg_createdate,
           max(mg_createdate) over (partition by mg_medianum) as max_created
    from MediaGenT
) t
where mg_createdate = max_created;
```

This is ANSI SQL and works on all modern DBMS

Answer (score 0):

```
Select mg_medianum 
from MediaGenT
  QUALIFY ROW_NUM() OVER (PARTITION BY mg_medianum Order by mg_createdate Desc)=1;
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect has this `qualify` syntax? That looks interesting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Seems to be [Teradata syntax](http://www.ssistalk.com/2010/02/10/sql-server-do-you-want-to-qualify-your-results/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a greatest-n-per-group query. One alternative is the one proposed by Gordon. The other one is using a left join:

```
select t1.* from MediaGenT t1
left join MediaGenT t2 on
t1.mg_medianum = t2.mgmedianum and t1.mg_createdate < t2.mg_createdate
where t2.mg_createdate is null
```

Efficiency of both queries may vary depending on the data distribution of the tables and the DBMS used.